# 画面のオーバーレイを使用中に別のビューの関数をdelegateで呼び出せない

Tags: swift

以下のようにAppDelegateを設定すると、UIViewContorllerの上にUIViewContorllerを乗っけられるのですが、この状態で上のビュー(OverlayViewController)のボタンを押しても,下のビュー(ViewController)の関数が呼び出されません。

なぜでしょうか？

`RecorgingButtonTapped---------`はprintされるのに、`pushRecording---------`はprintされないという状況です。特にエラーが出るわけでもないのに、pushRecordingを通過しないので不思議です。

これらの画面の上に画面を乗せるのは、以下のApple公式のサンプルをもとに作成しています。
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/streaming_an_ar_experience

**appDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

///- Tag: AppDelegate
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var overlayWindow: UIWindow!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        guard let window = window,
              let windowScene = window.windowScene else { fatalError() }
        
        // Create a window for the overlay.
        overlayWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let overlayViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(
            identifier: "OverlayViewController")
        overlayWindow.rootViewController = overlayViewController
        overlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        // Make sure the overlayWindow is always above the main window.
        overlayWindow.windowLevel = window.windowLevel + 1
        
        // Make the overlayWindow transparent so that the main window remains visible underneath.
        overlayWindow.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        return true
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,ViewControllerDelegate {

    func pushRecording()
    {
        print("pushRecording---------")
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        OverlayViewController().delegate = self // delegateを登録
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

**OverlayViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import ReplayKit

protocol ViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject  {
    func pushRecording()
}

class OverlayViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    
    @IBAction func RecorgingButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        print("RecorgingButtonTapped---------")
        delegate?.pushRecording()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

**Main.storyboad**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> なぜでしょうか？

正しいインスタンスに`delegate`を設定することができていないからです。

この行:

```
        OverlayViewController().delegate = self // delegateを登録
```

であなたは、

- アプリの実行と全く関係を持たない`OverlayViewController`のインスタンスを生成し
- そのインスタンスの`delegate`を設定し
- せっかく`delegate`を設定しながら、そのインスタンスを捨てる

と言うことをやっています。

オブジェクト指向言語を使っている場合、常に「どのインスタンスを使っているのか」をもっと意識し、単にコンパイルエラーが出なくなるだけでよしとしない癖をつけないといけません。

特にUIKitベースのプログラミングの場合、`OverlayViewController()`のように、引数のない`init()`でview controllerのインスタンスを生成するコードを見たら、99%間違っていると思った方が良いでしょう。

「`delegate`のメソッドが呼び出されるかどうか」だけでそれ以外のチェックはしていませんが、例えば上の1行を以下のように書き換える必要があるでしょう。

```
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let overlayViewController = appDelegate.overlayWindow.rootViewController as! OverlayViewController
        overlayViewController.delegate = self
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。示して頂いたコードで求めていた動作になりました。しかし、原理がいまひとつわかっていないのでもう少し伺いたいです。回答に「せっかくdelegateを設定しながら、そのインスタンスを捨てる」とありますが、このコード内では、どこの部分でインスタンスが捨てられてしまっているのでしょうか？

Comment: 「インスタンスを捨てる」という部分は、「インスタンスを保持していない」と読み替えるといいでしょう。`controller = OverlayViewController()`のように、変数に代入しないと保持できないし、その変数も、なんらかの手続きをしないと、捨てられてしまいますけど。